# Creating Custom Message using ROS Message (or Custom Message)

Tags: ros, catkin, geometry-msgs, message-generation, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My problem is similar to this [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/102661/custom-service-with-custom-message/), however, I do understand how to use messages within the same package.  My problem focuses on how to include a message from a separate package.  I have created a package with some "CustomMessage" that pulls from other packages and their messages.  These messages may be from a common package within my system, or a simple message type within geometry_msgs.

I have tried including the required dependencies in the CMakeLists.txt and Package.xml files, but for the code to work I have to include the package name in the variable type call.  For example:

```
common_package/Variable variable_text
```

If the package name is not included, I get something like:

```
Could not find messages which
  '../CustomMessage.msg'
  depends on.  Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?

Cannot locate message [PoseArray] in package [mission_control]
```

Is this the only way to include a custom message from another package, or is there a better way?  During my search, I found one other solution that followed this train of though at this [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/64553/how-do-you-locate-message-source-files-based-on-a-package-name-in-catkin/).  However, I was under the assumption that by correctly setting the CMakeLists.txt and Package.xml file correctly, it would understand the pathing.

For those who will ask, below is the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(mission_control)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS 
    project_common
    roscpp
    rospy
    geometry_msgs
    std_msgs
    message_generation
)

add_message_files(
   FILES
   CustomMessage1.msg
   CustomMessage2.msg
)

generate_messages(
    DEPENDENCIES
    geometry_msgs
    std_msgs
    project_common
)

catkin_package(
   #  INCLUDE_DIRS include
   #  LIBRARIES mission_control
   CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime project_common geometry_msgs std_msgs
   #  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Thanks for the help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103906/creating-custom-message-using-ros-message-(or-custom-message)/) by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message indicates that you use `PoseArray` without prefixing it with `geometry_msgs`. Can you please post your message file in the question?

Just to clarify the syntax in a message file - it is:

```
PackageName/VariableType variable_name
```

The `PackageName/` is left out when referring to message from the same package.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2013-11-22**:
Actually, that is exactly what I was asking.  I added that to my message file and the error went away as I mentioned in the question.  I was mainly wondering if that was the correct way or if there was another way.  My assumption was that it was correct, but thanks for confirming.